# CodenameOne background sendSMS with Android

Tags: codenameone

I have been developing an app with codenameOne which uses the sendSMS [Display.getInstance().sendSMS("number","message", false);] to send SMS messages in the background but now it's stopped working on Android.

It continues to work well on iOS where it always launches the mobile message  app and I can also get it to launch the message app in Android but the ability to send the message in the background would be preferred.

I have attempted to add permission to the build hints using key [android.xpermissions] and value [uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"] but now when sending a SMS it always launches the messaging app instead of sending in the background.

Has something changed server side when compiling the apk that now prevents this functionality? Is there a workaround for this or is there something I am missing to get the background SMS sending to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that feature was removed as Google no longer allows developers to submit apps to google play with the SMS permission. As a result we had to remove that permission and the functionality that goes with it, notice that sending interactive SMS's should still work.

See https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/01/05/googles-new-sms-and-call-permission-policy-is-crippling-apps-used-by-millions/